# Error while installing PSPP in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

I tried to install PSPP for 20.04 version. I could not get the required version and tried to install the version for 18.04. During installation I got the error message:

> Dependency is not satisfiable: libreadline 7(>=6.0)

[image]

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: The version of Ubuntu is 20.04.

Comment: i couldnot edit question

Comment: [edit] your post

Comment: I have edited the question....PLZ help thank you.

Comment: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/eoan/universe/base/pspp                 This worked. Happy